# Can't Center map on marker in gmap3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

So i tried to find some documentation about how to center the map on a marker,
but somehow it doesn't work for me.

In the example on the [Gmap3](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getgeoloc-54) page it works fine without adding the "center" to the map options,
for me even with the "center:latLng" it wouldn't work.

so i tried some different combination nothing really works for me..

then i tried to extract the latitude and longitude separately and checked the numbers i get 
on a site that allows to enter lat and lng, and i realized that the coords are not those of the marker, so i don't know if i extract them right or there is another problem.

this is my code right now-

```
$("#mapholder").gmap3({
    getgeoloc:{
        callback : function(latLng){
        //here is where i tried to get the lat and lng out of the latLng
            lat = parseFloat(latLng.A.toFixed(6));
            console.log(typeof(lat));
            lng = parseFloat(latLng.k.toFixed(6));
            lat_Lng = latLng;
            console.log("latitude: "+lat+" , longtitude: "+lng);
            console.log("typeof latlng: "+typeof(latLng));
            if (latLng){
                $("#mapholder").gmap3({
                    map:{
                        options:{
                            center:latLng,
                            zoom: 5
                        }
                    },
                    marker:{ 
                        latLng:latLng
                    }
                 });
             }
        }
    }
});
```

another way i tried it was

```
center:[lat,lng]
```

and even without any center like in the [demo](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getgeoloc-54) it didn't work.

Thanks a lot for any help!

**UPDATE**

could it have anything to do with the callback function that doesn't allow those parameters?

i also tried to add a data type to the marker so it would say "You are here!", this doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log("latitude: "+lat+" , longtitude: "+lng);` and what is the approximate location it should show?

Comment: D.Kasipovic - it gives an output of points but not where the marker is set. checked it via this site http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Can you post an online example somewhere?

Comment: http://wernersound.com/examples/gmap_example/ in the link MyPlaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script as it is works correct, there is an issue with your demo:

When gmap3 creates the map-instance while the "My Places"-tab is hidden #mapholder doesn't have a size(the center of the map is the top-left corner of the map in this case).

When you select the "My Places" -tab the first time after the map-instance has been created you must trigger the resize-event for the map and re-assign the center:

```
  $(link).fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $(link).addClass("current");
    if(link==='#myPlaceSection' && lat_Lng){
        $('#mapholder').gmap3({trigger:"resize"});
        $('#mapholder').gmap3({map:{options:{center:lat_Lng}}});
        lat_Lng=null;
      }
    }  
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that was it! thanks for taking the time and looking through the script in the link i posted i really appreciate it. i was struggling with it a lot. so every change i want to do int the map i need to do in the if condition?

Comment: the if-condition in my suggestion only matches  the first time you select the "My Places-tab" after the creation of the map.

Comment: ok now i see u set the lat_Lng to null. so now if i need to add markers or any other change on the map during input fields or what ever how u suggest i would do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the reference you need to give the latLong as below:

```
map:{
  options:{
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
  zoom: 5
},
```

[Reference is here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple?hl=fr).

Try this. This will work for you.

Comment: the coords i get out of the latLng using "lat = parseFloat(latLng.A.toFixed(6));" aren't correct.. how can i get the exact coords of the marker?

Comment: @Michael what are you getting in variable `latLng`?

Comment: an object lookin like this- "O {k: 32.066158, A: 34.77781900000002, toString: function, j: function, equals: function…}"

Comment: @Michael I think these are not coordinate so please give the full data that you are getting in that.

Comment: i checked these floats on this site http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html and they gave me my place just needed to switch between the variables in the src-code that i wrote so - lat = parseFloat(latLng.k.toFixed(6)); and lng = parseFloat(latLng.A.toFixed(6)); but still he wouldn't center the map according to these coords